# Jboss JPA Management and Hibernate ConnectionProvider

Tags: hibernate, jpa, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I'm working on Jboss Wildfly 9 and i'm fighting with this stucking situation in which i cannot use my custom runtime connection provider and the application server container:

I have this persistence unit defined inside my Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="MyUnit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>   
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.klopotek.core.connection.MyHibernateConnectionProvider" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

where

```
MyHibernateConnectionProvider implements org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider
```

interface with its

```
getConnection();
```

method.

I'm workging with multitenancy so i don't know at deployment time which tenant the user will send his request to. Of course this information will be available at runtime.

When i deploy my war into the server,  wildfly, asking for connection and receiving a null object, raises this exception:

```
s.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."sec-api.war#Klopotek-PU-Statistics": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
```

Till now i have worked specifying

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"/>
```

property inside the persistence.xml in order to avoid the exception. The runtime connection instantiation works pretty well.

In order to end my work i need to handle EntityManager object inside UserTransaction but, having disabled jboss jpa management, i cannot do it (jndi cannot find my persistence unit).

So is there a way to enable jboss.jpa and to specify some other properties in order to do not break my webapplication deployment?

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using? It doesn't appear you're using the provided one, based on the stack trace errors not including  jar file name)

Comment: I used the wildfly provided one... 4.3

Comment: Hmm ok.  what strategy are you using? Do you have a tenant identifier setup? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

Comment: I m simply able to get tenant from request. I can select the right datasource from a config file starting from tenant. From datasource jndi name i can get connection. MyhibernateConnectionProviderReturn it

Comment: I need to switch connection from a datasource to another at runtime

Comment: Right, but do you understand the relationship between tenant identifier and multitenantconnectionprovider? It's important to understand their relationship, even if you switch datasources.  You need both configured for this to work, which is likely the NPE